# Как имитировать нажатие 2-х клавиш, например: "Shift + f"?

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Есть код имитации нажатия одной клавиши:

```
    public static void simulateKey(final int KeyCode) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception when sendKeyDownUpSync", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Тут список всех кнопок (KeyCode): [Нажмите для показа](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent?hl=ru)

Вызов: simulateKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F); работает корректно и точно, имитирует нажатие "f".

---

НО:
Как имитировать нажатие 2-х клавиш?
Мне надо вместо: "f" выводить: "F".

Но, кода заглавной буквы нет и поэтому необходимо нажать сразу две: Shift + f

Comment: Вызвать последовательно два нажатия SHIFT и потом F? А, это андроид. Забудь)

Comment: Но Вы ведь в Андроиде вводите большие буквы, поэтому "забыть" я всегда успею!))
Может быть последовательно нажать на "CAPS_LOCK" и "f" есть возможность? Но и это не прокатывает)

Comment: Вопрос решился:
                        KeyEvent downShiftF = new KeyEvent(mDownTime, mEventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F, 5, KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON);
                        inst.sendKeySync(downShiftF);

Comment: woesss!
Щас подготовлю и опубликую.

Answer (score 0):

В примере [(ApiDemos)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalSampleInstrumentation.java) "Hello" с большой буквы пишут так:

```
    // Act like the user is typing some text.
    sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT));
    sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H);
    sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT));
    sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E);
    sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_L);
    sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_L);
    sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился так:

```
        public static void simulateKey(final int KeyCode) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mDownTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    mEventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                    Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
                    inst.sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(mDownTime, mEventTime,  KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyCode, 5, KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception when sendKeySync", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```